# What is the equivalent of Set X = Nothing in PHP?

Tags: php, asp-classic

Is:

```
<%
Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("SomeCOMObject")

Set Mail = Nothing
%>
```

the same as:

```
<?php
$Mail = new COM("SomeCOMObject");

$Mail->Close(); // <---- Not sure about this
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$mail = new Mail; //hello
unset($mail); //goodbye
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set $var to equal nothing like this:

```
$var = null;
```

To completely release the variable from memory, you do this:

```
unset($var);
```

Answer (score 1):

I beleive

```
$Mail = null;
unset($Mail);
```

Although I am likely mistaken.

Comment: One or the other is enough, depending on the exact intend (dunno what exactly `Nothing` does in ASP). You don't need to bleach, cut, slice, burn **and** kill a variable. :)

Comment: unset() also depends on variable scope. If unset() inside a function, even if passed by reference, only destroys the local variable.